# fscanf is duplicating numbers while reading from a file

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, scanf

I am trying to read numbers from a file and put them into a 2d array, but the first number of each line is being put into the place of the last number of the previous line.

output should look like this:

```
11  14  12  07  1   8.7
11  14  11  58  143 8.6
11  14  13  03  163 8.9
11  13  18  06  1   7.3
```

but instead comes out like this:

```
11  14  12  07  1   11
11  14  11  58  143 11
11  14  13  03  163 11
11  13  18  06  1   7.3
```

This is the loop that is putting the values into the array:

```
    double all_data[entry_counter-1][5];
    int col_counter = 0;
    int row_counter = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<=entry_counter/6-1; i++) {
        col_counter = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
            fscanf(input_file, "%lf\n", &v);

            all_data[row_counter][col_counter] = v;
            col_counter++;
        }
        row_counter++;
    }
```

Comment: Without a [MCVE], looks like boundary overrun scenario.

Comment: The array only has room for 5 items per row, indexed from 0 to 4. But the `j` loop counts from 0 to 5. BTW, there's no need for a separate `col_counter` since `j` and `col_counter` always have the the same value.

Comment: Did you mean to use `<` instead of `<=`?

Comment: double all_data[entry_counter-1][6]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is overly complicated and wrong.

This should do the job:

```
int cols = 6;
int rows = entry_counter / cols;
double all_data[rows][cols];

for(int row_counter = 0; row_counter < rows; row_counter++) {
    for (int col_counter = 0; col_counter < cols; col_counter++) {
        fscanf(input_file, "%lf\n", &all_data[row_counter][col_counter]);
    }
}
```

Keep it simple.